# IDE + manual build process

Tags: java, build-process

I will ask my question short and sweet, is there any formal way to write code using IDE and then build them using manual build process.If anyone has good links on internet, it is better to give

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's easy, and what is more important - convenient, in cases when your IDE project is based on some external build model e.g. Ant, Maven, probably SBT for Scala. In this case it's easy for external build to be synchronized with IDE. Also it's important whether your IDE monitors underlying filesystem changes inside project folder, as I believe it's going to be quite pain-full to click "Refresh" or something similar every time you build.

Popular IDE's provide options to import project from external models like Ant and Maven.

Personally I use this approach in one of my projects with Java, Maven and IntellijIdea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use maven. It has plugins to all popular IDEs. So, create maven project, write pom.xml, run `mvn install` and then run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (if you are using eclipse).

This will produce .project and .classpath. Now open eclipse, define classpath variable M2_REPO and import your project.

M2_REPO should be defined only once and should refer to local maven repository that is typically located under USER_HOME/.m2/repository.

For more details see documentation of maven.

I did not know this and always spent a lot of time synchronizing my IDE and ant build.xml. But now I am using maven and can forget about this hard work.